# Why is my gauge chart not being loaded?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-experience

I am trying to build a gauge chart with the JavaScript library called Zing Chart, but it is not even loaded. Why?

[image]

I did add the zing chart cdn as a static resource before that.
**gauge_chart.html**

```
<template>
  <lightning-card title="Gauge Chart" icon-name="utility:chart">
      <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid--pull-padded">
          <div if:true={isChartJsInitialized} class="slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-1">
              <canvas class="gaugechart" lwc:dom="manual"></canvas>
          </div>
          <div if:false={isChartJsInitialized} class="slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-1">
              Zing Chart Not loaded yet
          </div>
      </div>
  </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**gauge_chart.js**

```
import { LightningElement, track } from "lwc";
import zingchartlib from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/zingchartlib";
import { loadScript, loadStyle } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";
import { ShowToastEvent } from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";

export default class GaugeChart extends LightningElement {
  @track isZingChartInitialized;

  config = {
    type: "gauge",
    globals: {
      fontSize: 25
    },
    plotarea: {
      marginTop: 100
    },
    plot: {
      size: "100%",
      valueBox: {
        placement: "center",
        text: "%v",
        fontSize: 25,
        rules: [
          {
            rule: "%v == 1000000",
            text: "%v <br> Target achieved!"
          },
          {
            rule: "%v > 750000 && %v < 1000000",
            text: "%v <br> Way to go!"
          },
          {
            rule: "%v > 500000  && %v <= 750000",
            text: "%v <br> Almost there!"
          },
          {
            rule: "%v >= 250000 && %v <= 500000",
            text: "%v <br> Keep it up!"
          },
          {
            rule: "%v < 250000",
            text: "%v <br> We just started!"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      borderRadius: 5
    },
    scaleR: {
      aperture: 180,
      minValue: 0,
      maxValue: 1000000,
      step: 250000,
      center: {
        visible: false
      },
      tick: {
        visible: false
      },
      item: {
        offsetR: 0,
        rules: [
          {
            rule: "%i == 9",
            offsetX: 15
          }
        ]
      },
      labels: ["0", "250.000", "500.000", "750.000", "1.000.000"],
      ring: {
        size: 50,
        rules: [
          {
            rule: "%v < 250000",
            backgroundColor: "#E53935"
          },
          {
            rule: "%v >= 250000 && %v < 500000",
            backgroundColor: "#FFFF00"
          },
          {
            rule: "%v >= 500000 && %v < 750000",
            backgroundColor: "#3CB371"
          },
          {
            rule: "%v >= 750000",
            backgroundColor: "#29B6F6"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    series: [
      {
        values: [0],
        backgroundColor: "black",
        indicator: [10, 5, 5, 5, 0.75],
        animation: {
          effect: 2,
          method: 1,
          sequence: 4,
          speed: 900
        }
      }
    ]
  };

  renderedCallback() {
    if (this.isZingChartInitialized) {
      return;
    }
    this.isZingChartInitialized = true;

    Promise.all([loadScript(this, zingchartlib)])
      .then(() => {
        zingchart.render({
          id: this.template.querySelector("canvas.gaugechart"),
          data: config,
          height: 500,
          width: "100%"
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.dispatchEvent(
          new ShowToastEvent({
            title: "Error loading ZingChart",
            // message: error.message,
            variant: "error"
          })
        );
      });
  }
}
```

**gauge_chart.js-meta.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>    
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: Have you checked your developer console? Without a specific error, it'll be hard to identify a solution.

Comment: sfdcfox, I think so. Errors in the PROBLEMS tab (gauge_chart.js):

'loadStyle' is defined but never used. eslint(no-unused-vars) |
'zingchart' is not defined. eslint(no-undef) |
'config' is not defined. eslint(no-undef) |
'error' is defined but never used. eslint(no-unused-vars) | 

It seems that isn't possible to see lwc errors in the developer console. I'm using the vscode + Salesforce Extension Pack.

Comment: VS code errors won't help, those are really just warnings. And yes, you can get errors on the console in LWC. I do it all the time. Tell you what, though, I've got a few minutes, I'll try to replicate it.

Comment: Fo real? How I do that? Ok then, thx! =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a bit longer than strictly necessary to discover the problem, as the script's problem is generated as a Warning, not an Exception.

> aura_proddebug.js:56717 WARNING: Failed to load script at /resource/zingchart: Cannot assign to read only property 'JSON' of object '[object Object]' [Cannot assign to read only property 'JSON' of object '[object Object]']

I found this by using the Developer Console, clicking "Pause on Exceptions", then checking "Pause on Caught Exceptions", and then stepping through until I landed in the script. I'm not sure why "error" was unpopulated (I feel like this is a bug in the runtime), but there definitely is a problem. I probably would have noticed this sooner if I'd read the warnings properly.

I'm not going to research this any further. All I'll say is that this particular library is not compatible with Locker Service, so you'll need to use something else. I know that [d3js](https://d3js.org/) is compatible with Locker Service if you're looking for a way to animate charts.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, sfdcfox!